# How can I get the link of a comment?

Tags: support, comments

Like the question says, how can I get the link of a comment to a question or answer? For example, if I would like to reference a comment when asking a question or answering.

Comment: When something on the internet has a date on it, it's extremely common that the date will be a link to that something. That's a pattern found all over. For example, dates on tweets link to that tweet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click on the date that the comment was created.

[image]